# Why is this not the standard proof for the uniqueness of the limit (for sequences)?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

As the title suggests, I want to know why the following proof is not the standard one:

First we will show that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n=0$ converges to $0$.
Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $N=1$, for every $n>N$ we have
$$|x_n-0|=|0-0|=0<\epsilon.$$
Now let's assume by contradiction that $(x_n)$ has another limit $L\neq 0$.
For $\epsilon = |L|$ we have $\epsilon > 0$.
There exists some $N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $$|x_n-L|=|0-L|=|L|<\epsilon = |L|$$
which is a contradiction.
Now for the main proof:
Let's assume that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $L_1$ and $L_2$.
Then we get $(a_n-a_n)$ converges to $L_1-L_2$, but for every $n$ we have $a_n-a_n=0$, and we showed that the sequence defined by $x_n=0$
**has one and only one** limit.
Therefore $L_1-L_2=0$ and we get $L_1=L_2$.

It seems to be much more simple than the other two proofs I know.
This proof relies on the arithmetic rules for convergent sequences, but there is no circular logic because the arithmetic theorem doesn't rely on the uniqueness theorem. If you think this is not as simple, please show the proof which is used more often and is more simple.

Comment: You need uniqueness to even make sense out of the limit...if failed then just writing $\lim a_n=L$ would be ill defined.  But...the "standard" proof of uniqueness is no harder than what you wrote.  If the sequence converged to both $L_1, L_2$ with $|L_1-L_2|=\epsilon>0$ then take $n$ big enough so that $a_n$ is within $\frac {\epsilon}4$ of both $L_1, L_2$, which is obviously impossible

Comment: If one assumes the arithmetic rules for convergent sequences, then this proof is simple, or rather as simple as the proofs of the arithmetic rules to which you allude. :)

Comment: @user122916 Ok, since every real analysis book proves the arithmetic rules anyway, why don't they use the proof in the question?

Comment: I can't say why they don't, but it may just be a matter of taste. For example, for an elementary introduction, I like to introduce the ``$\epsilon/2$" style of argument with the example that limits are unique. Then students see it again with the arithmetic rules and get more used to it. For a more advanced text, they could take your approach, but I'm not sure it saves any lines of text.

Comment: @emanresu The proofs are equivalent. But it is more natural to prove the limit rules for sums/differences of sequences *after* the uniqueness has been established. Otherwise it would take great care (and potential for confusion) to even state the difference rule $\lim (a_n-b_n) = \lim a_n - \lim b_n$ if you could have multiple choices for the limits on both sides of the equal sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason this is not used is because this relies on the vector space structure (of the reals, which is where I assume you’re working in). What you wrote is fine, because the standard limit laws for addition and multiplication simply say if the two sequences converge to such and such value, then their product sum/converges to such and such value. Uniqueness/non-uniqueness plays no role here. But you should note that without proving uniqueness, the very symbol $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ becomes ambiguous, so one has to state the above theorems more carefully. The only way to salvage meaning is to then consider $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ as standing for the set of all points to which the sequence converges. As much as possible, we’d like to avoid dealing with set-valued objects.

However, the theorem (uniqueness of limits) holds much more generally in metric spaces, and also in Hausdorff topological spaces. For example, in the metric space setting, suppose $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ which converges to $\xi$ and $\eta$. To prove $\xi=\eta$, we proceed as follows: for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $d(x_n,\xi)<\epsilon$ and $d(x_n,\eta)<\epsilon$. Thus, by the triangle inequality, we have
\begin{align}
d(\xi,\eta)&\leq d(\xi,x_N)+d(x_N,\eta)<\epsilon+\epsilon=2\epsilon.
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, this implies (this is another standard exercise) that $d(\xi,\eta)=0$, and hence by the properties of the metric, it shows $\xi=\eta$. Here, one may decide to introduce $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, but it’s not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on dxiv's comment,

> Let's assume that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $L_1$ and $L_2$. Then we get $ (a_n−a_n)$ converges to $L_1−L_2$, ...

Isn't this something you have to prove, and can't just assume? I don't know that it's a huge deal, but if we're going to build from the ground up, I don't believe that's automatic.

And also, at that stage of your proof, wouldn't you have to say "$L_1-L_2$ is one of the values it converges to"? It feels like you may be sneaking in what you're trying to prove as an assumption with that sentence.